# sql - insert based on matching condition

Tags: mysql, insert

I have two tables:

```
person:
personid    | int(11)     | Primary Key, Auto-Increment, Index, Not Null
InternalID  | varchar(10) |
FirstName   | mediumtext  |
LastName    | mediumtext  |

contact:
contactid    | int(11) | Primary Key, Auto-Increment, Index, Not Null
personid     | int(11) | Index
MobilePhone1 | int(8)  |
```

There is a relation between the two tables as follows:
[image]

I have already populated the person table. Now I wish to update the contact table. I have a list of phone numbers along with the names in an excel sheet. How do I insert the phone numbers in a statement that can look for the name in the person table and match the correct personid ?

Comment: Hello @user2114721 What's the structure of your excel file? Does it contains separate Fistname and Lastname like the `person` table?

Comment: Hello, yes it has a column for phone number, one column First name, and the last name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for this

```
    INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

I hope that clears your query :)

Comment: Am quite stuck,

Here is what I came up with.  I know personid need to be as a condition?

    INSERT INTO contact ([personid], [MobilePhone1], [MobilePhone2])
    SELECT [personid], 
    FROM person
    WHERE personid = personid